# Github Action executes old configuration

Tags: github, github-actions

We use this Github Action:

```
# .github/workflows/pr-verify.yml
name: Verify Pull Request
on: # yamllint disable-line rule:truthy
  pull_request_target:
    types: [opened, edited, synchronize, reopened, ready_for_review]
# yamllint disable rule:line-length
jobs:
  pr-verify:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Verify Pull Request
    if: github.event_name != 'pull_request_target' || !github.event.pull_request.draft
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@8e5e7e5ab8b370d6c329ec480221332ada57f0ab # v3.5.2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
      - uses: actions/setup-node@64ed1c7eab4cce3362f8c340dee64e5eaeef8f7c # v3
        with:
          node-version: "16"
      - name: Install renovate
        run: npm i -g renovate
      - name: Validate config
        run: renovate-config-validator
        env:
          RENOVATE_CONFIG_FILE: .github/renovate.json5
```

Which fails for every PR with this message:

```
 INFO: Validating .github/renovate.json5
ERROR: .github/renovate.json5 is not valid Renovate config
       "err": {
         "message": "structuredClone is not defined",
         "stack": "ReferenceError: structuredClone is not defined\n    at massageConfig (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.0/x64/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/config/massage.ts:19:26)\n    at validate (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.0/x64/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/config-validator.ts:36:39)\n    at /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.20.0/x64/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/config-validator.ts:119:17"
```

The issue is `npm i -g renovate` which installs the latest version, which needs a newer Node.js version.

I created PR to updated the node version to: `node-version: "18"`

But GithubAction still executes the old configuration.

I can't merge the PR which will fix the issue.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

See [docs for "on: pull_request_target"](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target)

The Github Action uses the code of the base branch (which is in most cases "main").

You need to force-push the changes to `.github/workflows/pr-verify.yml` if the current setup always fails.